# Why isn't my variable incrementing in my for loop?

Tags: javascript

I create some image elements with JS, and I want that when I click in each image have a different number associated. But the problem is addEventListener just take the last number of the FOR. Some help pls.

For example, when I click on the second image the number that appear on the alert is 6.

```js
body = document.body;
test = 1;

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = 'https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3lynx_200.png';
  img.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert(test);
  });
  body.appendChild(img);

  test = test + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've created a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)-- the click handler will refer to the value of `test` *when it runs*, which is after the loop has executed and increased the value of `test` to the number of items in the loop.

There's a few ways around this-- the easiest may be to put the number in a data attribute on the element and reference that data attribute:

```js
test = 1;

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = 'https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3lynx_200.png';
  img.dataset.idx = test;
  img.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.dataset.idx);
  });
  document.body.appendChild(img);

  test = test + 1;
}
```

Or you can rewrite your function to eliminate the outer-closure, and use a closure variable block-scoped to the iteration:

```js
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  let currentIndex = i;
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = 'https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3lynx_200.png';
  img.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log(currentIndex);
  });
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```